# Increasing the Hadwiger number by making any pair of non-adjacent points adjacent

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-minors, hadwiger-conjecture

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph. The Hadwiger number $\eta(G)$ of $G$ is defined to be the largest positive integer $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the complete graph $K_n$ is a [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) of $G$.

We say that a graph is *vertex-critical* if removing any vertex reduces the chromatic number.

**Question.** What is an example of a connected, non-complete vertex-critical graph $G=(V,E)$ with the following property?

> Adding any edge increases the Hadwiger number -- or more formally: for $v\neq w \in V$ with $\{v,w\}\notin E$ we get $$\eta\big((V,E\cup\big\{\{v,w\}\big\})\big) > \eta\big((V,E)\big).$$

**Motivation.** Any minimal counterexample to [Hadwiger's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_(graph_theory)) has the properties given in the question.